# How to prevent or workaround Sysprep destroying certificate's private key

Tags: certificate, sysprep, private-key

I have a Windows 10 image which contains a Certificate to be used by the main application. However, after I run a `sysprep /generalize` on the image, the Certificate's private key appears to be destroyed.

If I run `certlm.msc`, then in Personal \ Certificates, I right click on my certificate and select "Manage Private Keys..." I get an error:

> No keys found for certificate!

Also, if I attempt to Export it tells me

> Note: The associated private key cannot be found. Only the certificate can be exported.

On the other hand, prior to the Sysprep, I can "Manage Private Keys" and the Export tells me the "associated private key is marked as not exportable"

I've also read [here](https://github.com/dsccommunity/CertificateDsc/issues/129) that private key is indeed lost after a sysprep.

Where is the private key stored and how can I prevent or work around this? Is it possible, for example, to save the private key prior to the Sysprep and then copy it back to wherever it was afterwards? The users on the device now have different SIDs, is this related (maybe the private key is tied to a specific SID)?

I have read around about this, and various sites have pointed me to a few locations where they could exist:

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` - There are two files in here. After the sysprep, a third file is created. This third file has the same prefix as one of the original two.  (I have tried removing this third file but it doesn't help)

`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys` - This dir is empty both before and after the sysprep.

**Edit**: I checked every subdirectory of `Crypto` and they are all identical before and after the sysprep.

`C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\{{SID}}`  - the `Crypto` dir does not exist before or after the Sysprep.

`C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates` is empty before and after the Sysprep.

**Edit**

I also checked in the registry in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Certificates` and found a certificate with a thumbprint matching the one in question. I also found in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\MY\Keys` a key matching the "Subject Key Identifier" of my certificate, it also containing a value. Unfortunately both are identical before and after the sysprep too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is addressed in the non-Microsoft bug-report
[Lost Private Key after sysprep #129](https://github.com/dsccommunity/CertificateDsc/issues/129),
where the last entry explains the problem:

> The Public key is (usually) written to registry, and the Private key
> written to file (never stored together, unless exported to PFX),
> either with system/machine files or User data. The point is that it's
> only 'linked' by the .Net object, but not really the same thing at
> all, and stored differently.
>
> When the cert request is still stored with all info, a /repairstore
> can fix that issue. But sysprep destroys personal data to generalise
> the machine, hence probably why I think it's lost. Even if the file is
> still there, it can be inaccessible, because of permissions.
>
> Anyhow, up until .Net 4.8 (with GetRSAPrivateKey()) there's no easy
> way to get the Private key, and I'm yet to find a nice way to find if
> the Private key is actually available on the system or not (something
> quick we can run every 15min).
> Until then, there's not much we can do on the resource side.

Conclusion: There's no solution. You might be able to add a
post-install task to the image that could reinstall the certificate.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw that, but I was thinking if I backed up the data prior to it being destroyed that I could restore it post-sysprep... If only I knew which file it was!

Comment: This [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234477/windows-certificates-where-is-private-key-located) will point you to the containing folder. Mine is at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18`. You might be able to locate the file by its date, but I don't know if just copying the file is enough.

Comment: Hmm... Took a look in the locations from that post, compared every file in every subdir (including that one) of `Crypto\ ` - its state before and after sysprep, including permissions & owner, and other than that extra file that I mentioned in the OP, they are identical.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you don't manage to identify the private key file? Here is a brute-force method that might work: Install the excellent [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) from voidtools, let it index the disk and set it to view all files in reverse order of date. Then delete and reinstall the certificate and try to identify the file that way.